# Can Laravels ioc container use autoloaded namespaces?

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel, ioc-container, autoload

Lets say I have a class `MyClass` in `app/repository/MyClass.php` in the `Repository` namespace:

```
namespace Repository;

class MyClass { ... }
```

I can bind this using the ioc container:

```
App::bind('SomeClass', 'Repository\MyClass');
```

Same thing with model dependencies:

```
SomeClass extends Eloquent{

    public function dependency()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('Models\Dependency');
    }        

}
```

One solution is to create aliases in `app.php`, but this has to be done for every single file that I want to have automatically namespaced:

```
'MyClass' => 'Repository\MyClass'
```

Is it possible to make the ioc container recognize the correct namespace for the classes without using aliases? Can we in any way use Composer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible unless you want to register an alias for every class in your namespaces. My recent Laravel 4 project has IOC Container bindings to namespaced classes which I declared explicitly.

`App::bind('Foo\Bar\Repositories\UserRepositoryInterface', 'Foo\Bar\Repositories\DbUserRepository');`

Comment: I know it's a little tedious, but I found that Sublime Text really makes this a breeze with multiple editing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
cd /path/to/laravel/
php composer dump-autoload
```

to have laravel see all the (new) classes and load them correctly

Answer (score 0):

Add `app/repository` to the autoload section of the composer.json file, like this for example:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
         "app/commands",
         "app/controllers",
         "app/models",
         "app/database/migrations",
         "app/database/seeds",
         "app/tests/TestCase.php",
         "app/repository"
    ]
},
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Also no luck. I think this just autoloads the files, so I can avoid using require(). It doesn't load the namespaces.